# How to create a GluonTS dataset from Stock/Equity, OHLCV, price data

Tags: dataset, gluon, huggingface-datasets

I have been struggling with getting a GluonTS dataset from a .csv file populated with OHLCV equity data. Does anyone know the best way to get a dataset that is compatible with GluonTS and HuggingFace from a file like depicted here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTjMq.png)

into a databaseDict object like depicted here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSTFu.png)

This is the notebook im trying to get my data to be compatible with:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/examples/time-series-transformers.ipynb

Towards the end of the notebook it suggest using the following notebook to make your own datasets:

https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/examples/time_series_datasets.ipynb

This is the notebook in which i've gotten the closest to making work, but I cant make it work in a way that would actually make sense.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sQvyZsTSpwhIcmcyg-c3YCfm4qJt6VhZ?usp=sharing

There should be a dataset entry for every day of price data.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I created this function, I don't yet if it works with hugging face but you can try it:

```
import pandas as pd
from gluonts.dataset.common import MetaData, TrainDatasets
from gluonts.dataset.pandas import PandasDataset
def get_gluonts_format(df: pd.DataFrame, target, freq, prediction_length, test_length) -> TrainDatasets:
       
    meta = MetaData(freq=freq, prediction_length=prediction_length)
    train = PandasDataset(df_pandas[: -test_length], target=target)
    test = PandasDataset(df, target=target)
    df_gluonts = TrainDatasets(metadata=meta, train=train, test=test)
    return df_gluonts
```

then you can call df_gluonts.train or df_gluonts.test to retrieve train and test.